# How to show that a convex domain is $D$ is open half plane if $u$ is convex.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $D$ be a proper convex domain of $\mathbb C$ and $u : D \to \mathbb R$ be the function $$  u(z) = \inf \{|z - w| : w\in\mathrm{boundary}(D) \}.  $$ Claim: $u$ is harmonic iff $D$ is an open half plane.

If $ D $ is an open halfplane, for example $ D= \{z : \Im z > 0\} $ then $ u(z)= u(x+iy) = y $ which is harmonic. It is similar in the case of other open half-planes.

The converse part  I am not able to prove.  If $ D $ is not an open half plane then $ u $ may not have partial derivatives at all; for example, if we take $D$ as first quadrant, then $ u(z) =\min\{x,y\}. $
How do I prove this?

Comment: half-planes are characterized by the fact that they have a unique support line, so maybe assuming that $D$ has at least 2 distinct support lines and seeing if you can get a point where the distance to the boundary is attained by the perpendiculars on at least $2$ such and then perturbing it a little works to prove what you want

Comment: @Conrad How exactly is this support line defined? Please give some details

Comment: any (closed) convex set has supporting lines for any boundary point and it is the intersection of all the supporting half-planes; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane for definition